# Intersection of an infinite number of slabs

Tags: convex-analysis

I am trying to illustrate the definition in Example 2.8 in Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook).

[image: This is the definition from page 37 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization]

---

As I suspect, I should reach to something like the graph in Figure 2.13. but my plot looks different. I don't know what's wrong with my understanding.

This is my Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
def MyPlot(x1, x2):
    plt.plot(t, x1 * np.cos( t) + x2 * np.cos(2* t))

t = np.linspace(0, math.pi, 100)  # Create a list of evenly-spaced numbers over the range

x1 = np.linspace(-10,10, 4)
x2 = np.linspace(-10,10, 4)
print ( x1)

for i in x1: 
    for j in x2: 
        MyPlot(i,j)

plt.show()
```

---

I got the following plot

[image: The figure I get]

but should have gotten the following

[image: This is what I should get]

Comment: What have you done to confine $x$ to $S$?

Comment: Scaling the range of x does not change the plot except for a scale. I take a range of (-10 , 10) without loss of generality @Ali

Comment: The set $S$ includes only values of $x$ satisfying a particular property. What have you done to ensure that property is satisfied by the values of $x$ for which you are plotting?

Comment: Nothing.
Because I draw it for several $x$s that are not necessarily in $S$. Verifying that is the next step I think. Am I right? @Ali

Comment: Well yes. If you exclude values of $x$ that don't satisfy the property then you should get something that looks more like the plot in the book.

Comment: I am plotting "all" of them... so it should be included.... @Ali

Comment: The plot in the book is just for a couple of random values of $x\in S$ and their mean. There are indeed lines among those that you have plotted that would have done the job just as well. But I'm not sure this exercise will teach you anything about convex optimisation.

Comment: So I can pass through it and let it be unsolved. Because non of the ones I have plotted behave similarly to the one in the book. But It seems there is nothing to worry about. @Ali